# Firefox bookmarks folder icon

Tags: firefox, icons, bookmarks

Is there a way to assign a custom icon to a folder in Firefox bookmarks?

That way not all folders would look the same, so I could delete the names and save some space in the bookmarks bar.

Comment: There's probably an add-on for that.

Comment: There used to be a custom add on for older firefox versions. I remember using it. But since firefox 2.xx it stopped working (and as I remember, development stopped) so now I'm looking to see if there is something which will work with 3.5.xx. Of course, I looked at mozilla's pages before asking. Alas, didn't find any.

Comment: Looks like it might be time for someone to take over that old one and brush it off for FF3

Comment: Excellent. I knew I could count on you for the job. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Idigas - if you're getting bored waiting, there's a fair amount of talk on Mozilla's forums about how to do it manually.  See http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?t=565229 and http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?t=566896

It would seem the userchrome.js extension should allow you to edit these folder appearances.

Answer (score 1):

As of Apr 2020  I was able to assign a custom icon to a folder on Firefox browser (v75) bookmark bar. Updated userChrome.css in the profile folder.

I followed the simple instructions here:
https://superuser.com/a/262502/745358

Answer (score 0):

I'm very late in this thread, but I was looking for the same thing. Turns out it seems [samfind](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/samfind-bookmarks-bar/) does the job.

I say it seems because I did not try it yet, but the features are pretty clearly expressed and meet the requirements stated by the OP.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that [Bookmark Favicon Changer](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/bookmark-favicon-changer/) works for folders too