# Can you customize individual icons for folders on the bookmarks bar in Firefox 4?

Tags: icons, bookmarks, firefox

I have a number of folders on my bookmarks bar in firefox.  I'd like to be able to change the icons for a few them to match the category they represent.  Is this possible?  If so, how?

My suspicion is that it's not built in to firefox itself, because changing the icon is what distinguishes a normal bookmark from a folder (it would break the UI metaphor they're using).  But I'm not opposed to using an extension for this, if one exists.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's possible by using the [userChrome.css](http://kb.mozillazine.org/UserChrome.css) file:

> To create this file, use your
>   operating system tools.
>
> Go to your **profile folder** (`%appdata%\Mozilla\Firefox\Profile\######.default`). Then go to
>   the **chrome** folder there, creating it
>   if necessary. In the chrome folder,
>   create a plain text file named
>   **userChrome.css**

To modify the icon of a folder named `test`, enter this to the `userChrome.css` file:

```
/*
 * Do not remove the @namespace line -- it's required for correct functioning
 */
@namespace url("http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul"); /* set default namespace to XUL */

#personal-bookmarks .bookmark-item[container][label="test"] {
 list-style-image:url('gmail.png') !important;
 -moz-image-region:auto !important;
}
```

Place the folder icon(s) in the same folder where `userChrome.css` resides

The result should look something like this:

[image]

Comment:  Tried this in Apr 2020, it worked !  Was able to change folder icon .Thanks.

Comment: Hmm, just tried it in July 2020, but it didn't change. I'm using Firefox Portable - does that matter? Path to file is: ...PortableApps/FirefoxPortable/Data/profile/chrome/userChrome.css

Comment: This worked for me, though I needed to set the value of `toolkit.legacyUserProfileCustomizations.stylesheets` to True (in about:config)